# Extract string between different special symbols

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I am having following string in my query

`.\ABC\ABC\2021\02\24\ABC__123_123_123_ABC123.txt`

beginning with a period from which I need to extract the segment between the final \ and the file extension period, meaning following expected result

`ABC__123_123_123_ABC123`

Am fairly new to using REGEXP and couldn't help myself to an elegant (or workable) solution with what Q&A here or else. In all queries the pattern is the same in quantity and order but for my growth of knowledge I'd prefer to not just count and cut.

Comment: I understand, i will post for you an example with regular expression, maybe it will also work with **SQL**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function such as

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'(.*\\)(.*)\.(.*)','\2')
```

in order to extract the piece starting from the last slash upto the dot. Preceding slashes in `\\` and `\.` are used as escape characters to distinguish the special characters and our intended `\` and `.` characters.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=25ccf9aeaaf3d845661b40abb0227c8c)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You need just [regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) and simple regexp `([^\]+)\.[^.]*$`

```sql
select
 regexp_substr(
   '.\ABC\ABC\2021\02\24\ABC__123_123_123_ABC123.txt',
   '([^\]+)\.[^.]*$',
   1, -- position
   1, -- occurence
   null, -- match_parameter 
   1  -- subexpr 
) substring 
from dual;
```

`([^\]+)\.[^.]*$` means:

- `([^\]+)` - find one or more(`+`) any characters except slash(`[]` - set, `^` - negative, ie except) and name it as group \1(subexpression #1)
- `\.` - then simple dot (`.` is a special character which means any character, so we need to "escape" it using `\` which is an escape character)
- `[^.]*` - zero or more any characters except `.`
- `$` - end of line

So this regexp means: find a substring which consist from: one or more any characters except slash followed by dot followed by zero or more any characters except dot and it should be in the end of string. And `subexpr` parameter = 1, says oracle to return first subexpression (ie first matched group in `(...)`)

Other parameters you can find in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - will educate myself further the coming week. This looks really helpful for me... didn't get far with the cheat sheets etc but with this as a working example I can dabble around and learn
For now Barbaros' formulation was accepted by the DB and works as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple full compatible example with **Oracle 11g R2**, **PCRE2** **and some other languages.**

**Oracle 11g R2** using function **substr** ([Reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm))

```
 select
 regexp_substr(
   '.\ABC\ABC\2021\02\24\ABC__123_123_123_ABC123.txt',
   '((\w)+(_){2}(((\d){3}(_)){3}){1}((\w)+(\d)+){1}){1}',
   1, 
   1
 ) substring 
from dual;
```

Pattern: `((\w)+(_){2}(((\d){3}(_)){3}){1}((\w)+(\d)+){1}){1}`

Result: **ABC__123_123_123_ABC123**

Just as simple as it can be, regular expressions always follow a minimal standard, as you can see portability also provided, just for the case someone else is interested in going the simplest way.

Hopefully, this will help you out!

Comment: This is similar to what I tried, but didn't work on the DB, also though syntax is right.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support PCRE and you don't need to escape `_-` in []

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov yes, i know, i will change it for this exact case

Comment: @TobiasB, i updated my answer, portability provided.

Comment: Oh thank you! Haha I see I will have both frustration and fun learning how to use this nice function properly :)